# I am looking to copy latest data entered in excel to be copied to another excel file in share point without openning it. Is it possible?

Tags: sharepoint, copy-paste, excel-2013

I have created a work tracker with online help for my team. Couldn't attach it in here.
If needed, let me know your e-mail address so I can forward it to you.

I want that whenever any of my team member is updating the file on their local storage, then the updated lines should be copied in sharepoint as well without openning any other file.

Please suggest the best way, either to create new file on every instance or to copy the data in to the first empty row of destination.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why people can't edit the file in the browser and use the co-authoring features of Excel Online?

Comment: SharePoint is not allowing co-authoring for unknown reason. I have changed the file to .xls and converted all tables as values in order to enable "Share Workbook" in excel. The co-authoring works perfect in share drive but it doesn't in Share Point. Since the file will be used by people outside organization as well, I need Co-authoring from share point. The other way I thought of updating SharePoint list with a Macro in excel after every change.

Comment: The file will execute Macros with button click. Browser version do not suppot this. I have 40 people to coauthor the file. SharePoint 2013 doesn't allow this either. So an automated feed from everyone's local machine to SharePoint list can work. But I am not sure how to do it. The other thoughts are keeping every individuals file in SharePoint and create a connection manually to MS Access, for updating the SharePoint list with specific table. Can anyone suggest a solution around my scenario!